# Annotation/Attribute convention for fields to display in list views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'd like to add an Attribute to an entity (or to properties of an entity) that describe which fields to show in a list view context and in which order. Is there an existing Annotation class that would handle this or should I implement my own?

I was thinking of something like:

```
[ListDisplayFields(new string[]{"Title", "Category", "Updated"})]
public class Article
{
```

But I can think of a bunch of other functionality to add in as well (List view titles which may differ from item view, etc.) Is it a bad idea to try to get too clever with attributes?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a bad idea to try to get too clever with attributes?

In my opinion it is a bad idea. You should create separate view models for list view and single-item view.

When your project grows, you will quickly notice that the requirements of a list view and single-item view differ from your persisted entities. Very often you will want to show only a subset of entity's properties in single-item view. On the other hand, in a list view you might need to display some additional information coming from different entities (e.g. current stock, total orders last month).

You can use [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) and its [queryable extensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) to make projections to view models easier in queries.